# hide console window when ffmpeg opened

Tags: ffmpeg

How can i hide the console when ffmpeg executed

```
@echo off
mkdir "My records"
set outputpath=My records\record_%date:~-2,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%_%time:~-11,2%%time:~-8,2%.mp3
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -y -t 01:00:00 "%outputpath%" 
FOR /F %%A IN ('CMDOW ˆ| FIND "HideMePlease"') DO CMDOW %%A /HID
```

[console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMDqN.png)

Comment: Click the minimise button?

Comment: @DavidPostill and the funniest mod award goes to ....... mr.David \O/

Comment: i found a workaround, i used a vbs file to run the ffmpeg.exe file without showing the command console

Comment: Since you found a solution you can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

i used a vbs file to run the ffmpeg.exe with showing the console

```
set objShell = createobject("wscript.shell")  
objShell.Run("""options.bat"" ""-SignatureUpdate""") , 0
```